# python parse json dates into iso standard

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-requests

I have a python script for extracting data from certain website and return data into array of JSON objects but in the date section instead of return dates into ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) it return normal date (DD-MM-YYY) what approach should I use to fix this.

```
import requests
import json, codecs
from datetime import datetime
URL = 'http://tfda.go.tz/portal/en/trader_module/trader_module/getRegisteredDrugs_products'
payload = "draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=no&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=& columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=certificate_no&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=brand_name&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=classification_name&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=common_name&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=dosage_form&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=product_strength&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=registrant&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=registrant_country&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B9%5D%5Bdata%5D=manufacturer&columns%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B9%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B10%5D%5Bdata%5D=manufacturer_country&columns%5B10%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B10%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B11%5D%5Bdata%5D=expiry_date&columns%5B11%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B11%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B12%5D%5Bdata%5D=id&columns%5B12%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B12%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=3911&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=False"
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    s.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'})
    res = s.post(URL, data = payload)

dumped = ''
for data in res.json()['data']:
    serial = data['no']
    id_no = data['id']
    certno = data['certificate_no']
    brndname = data['brand_name']
    clssification = data['classification_name']
    common_name = data['common_name']
    dosage_form = data['dosage_form']
    expiry_date = data['expiry_date']
    manufacturer = data['manufacturer']
    manufacturer_country = data['manufacturer_country']
    product_strength = data['product_strength']
    registrant = data['registrant']
    registrant_country = data['registrant_country']
    output = (serial,certno,brndname,clssification,common_name,dosage_form,expiry_date,manufacturer, manufacturer_country,product_strength,registrant, registrant_country)

     data = {'common_name':common_name,'brandname':brndname, 'classification_name':clssification,'cerficate_number':certno,'registrant':registrant, 'registrant_country':registrant_country, 'manufacturer':manufacturer, 'manufacturer_country':manufacturer_country, 'product_strength':product_strength, 'dosage_form':dosage_form, 'expiry_date':expiry_date}
output = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=True, sort_key=True, indent=2)
dumped = dumped + outputdata = {'common_name':common_name,'brandname':brndname, 'classification_name':clssification,'cerficate_number':certno,'registrant':registrant, 'registrant_country':registrant_country, 'manufacturer':manufacturer, 'manufacturer_country':manufacturer_country, 'product_strength':product_strength, 'dosage_form':dosage_form, 'expiry_date':expiry_date}
output = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=True, sort_key=True, indent=2)
dumped = dumped + output

print(dumped)
```

And here is the screenshot of my output
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMBUB.png)

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strptime` to convert your string date to datetime object and then use `strftime` to convert it to your required format.

**Ex:**

```
from datetime import datetime
expiry_date = datetime.strptime(data['expiry_date'], "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```